# comparing two data sets and add asterisk if column value is 1 in c #

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, concatenation

I have two data set to compare and exclude same records 
 here is my code which is working perfectly

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (DataRow dr2 in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string table2 = dr2["code"].ToString();
            string deletedVchr = dr2["type"].ToString();
            if (i.ToString() == table2.ToString() && deletedVchr == "0")
            {
              found = true;
            }
         }
         if (!found )
         dsnew.Tables[0].Rows.Add(i);              
      }
```

I just want to add asterisk(*)  in data set if column(type) of table 1 has 
value 1

here is my tables

```
             Table 1
           code          type
             1            0
             2            1  

     Table 2
      code
        0
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
        7
        8
        9
       10
     Expected Record Table 
          code
            0
            2*
            3
            4
            5
            6
            7
            8
            9
           10
```

Comment: What values can be present in the Type column of Table 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            bool found = false;
            bool asterisk = false;
            foreach (DataRow dr2 in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                string table2 = dr2["code"].ToString();
                string deletedVchr = dr2["type"].ToString();
                if (i.ToString() == table2.ToString() && deletedVchr == "0")
                {
                  found = true;
                }
                else if (i.ToString() == table2.ToString() && deletedVchr == "1")
                {
                  asterisk = true;
                }
             }
             if (!found && !asterisk)
                dsnew.Tables[0].Rows.Add(i); 
             if(asterisk)
                dsnew.Tables[0].Rows.Add(i+"*");        
          }
```